# Pack an executable inside a shared library?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to pack an executable into a shared library and upon calling a function inside the said library:

- unpack the executable
- use the executable through `fork`

The reason I am asking is because I was recently faced with a situation where my shared library was being loaded in a "sandbox" environment (maybe chroot based) and I would have really like the possibility of spawning a separate process for an executable (loose coupling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have permission to write to a directory on a filesystem that isn't mounted `noexec`, then you could just store the executable in a large array of `unsigned char` and write it out with `fwrite`, then use `fork`/`exec` to run it.

Really though, the best solution is just to use `fork()` *without* `exec` - just have the child side call into a different function after the `fork()` (and then exit with `_exit()` when that function is done).

Comment: How about if I don't have access to such directory?  ( I have already implemented a solution based on `fork` + function)

Comment: Then it can't really be done - but that's pretty much because there's no point doing so (`exec` replaces the currently executing image with one from a file - on the other hand replacing the currently executing image with part of itself is pretty pointless, since you can just directly call in to that part).

Answer (score 1):

Completely plausible.

```
static const char program[] = {
    0x7f, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x43, 0x05, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x1a, 0x00, 0x43, 0x05,
    0x1a, 0x00, 0x43, 0x05, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xb9, 0x31, 0x00, 0x43,
    0x05, 0xb2, 0x0d, 0xcd, 0x80, 0x25, 0x20, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x93, 0xcd,
    0x80, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c,
    0x64, 0x0a
};

void hello(void) {
    int fd;
    pid_t child;
    char name[1024];
    char *tmp = getenv("TEMP") ?: getenv("TMP") ?: "/tmp";
    if (strlen(tmp) > sizeof(name) - 8) return;
    sprintf(name, "%s/XXXXXX", tmp);
    fd = mkstemp(name);
    if (fd == -1) return;
    if (write(fd, program, sizeof(program)) < sizeof(program)) {
        close(fd);
        unlink(name);
        return;
    }
    fchmod(fd, 0700);
    close(fd);
    (child = fork()) ? waitpid(child, 0, 0) : execl(name, name);
    unlink(name);
}
```

When run on Linux x86 or compatible, this function will print "hello, world" to the screen.

However, I would definitely not recommend this.  If you want a separate binary, just ship a separate binary, and require that it be installed in the sandbox along with your library.